# IWorkbenchPage#resetPerspective Deletes Perspective

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

I don't think it's possible to set the perspective to `null` after an application is created and the default one is loaded, yet E4 does it somehow, in the method `resetPerspective` even:

```
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    page.resetPerspective();
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> System.out.println(page.getPerspective())); // null
```

What is the correct way (ideally for both E3 and E4) to reset the perspective?

Comment: That code doesn't return null for me, I get the expected current perspective. Where are you running it?

Comment: @greg-449 Eclipse 4.5.2. The code is inside `WorkbenchAdvisor#postStartup`. I'm kind of relieved because it sounds like this is not the intended behavior.

Comment: Under which conditions do you need to reset perspective?

Comment: @svasa Valid question, I have no idea why it is done this way (legacy code). My current "fix" is to just don't do it. Still I'd feel better if I didn't delete old code but replaced it with the working E4 equivalent.

Comment: @greg-449 @svasa I just got a ticket that even using `org.eclipse.ui.window.resetPerspective` deletes the perspective.